# Typescript union type bug

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm using NgRx and I have a problem with union type, here is my code

in auth.actions.ts:

```
export class Login implements Action{
    readonly type = types.LOGIN;
    
    constructor(public user: Buyer | Seller, public userType: userTypes){}
}
```

in auth.reducer.ts:

```
export interface State {
    isLoggedIn: boolean,
    userType: userTypes,
    user: Buyer | Seller
}
```

in buyer.model.ts

```
import { User } from './user.model';

export class Buyer implements User{
    constructor(public firstName: string, public lastName: string,
        public email: string, public token: string){}
}
```

in auth.service.ts:

```
 const user = new Buyer('Omar', 'zahir', 'a@b.com', result.token);
 this.store.dispatch(new Login(user , userTypes.BUYER));
```

in mycomponent.ts

```
this.store.select('auth').subscribe(authData => {
  this.isLoggedIn = authData.isLoggedIn;
  this.name = authData.user.firstName
      
})
```

it gives me this error

```
Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Buyer | Seller'.
  Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'Seller'.
```

it only suggests 'user.email' and 'user.token' as they are the only 2 properties in common between Buyer and Seller classes.
what should I do?

Comment: If `authData.user` may be either a `Buyer` or a `Seller`, and one of those doesn't have a `firstName` property, then you can't access `authData.user.firstName` safely.  What do you want your code to do if `authData.user` is a `Seller`?

Comment: It should suggest other fields that don't exist on  Buyer

Comment: Which concepts are you familiar with?: 1. downcasts 2. discriminated unions 3. type guards

Comment: Lesiak I'm familiar with the last 2

Comment: Then either make a discriminated union out of Login (it already has a discriminator userType) or make a type guard for user (instanceof will work, since you are using a class)